# TypeError: db.collection is not a function at handleSignIn

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, vite

So i am using firebase auth to register with email and password from where i am storing email, approvalStatus and approvalCode into firestore db called "users" where each doc describes each user

In sign in page im taking input of email , password and approvalCode and trying to match with the approvalCode stored in DB and then it should navigate to "/in"

Please help me with this :)

FIREBASE.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export {app, auth, db};
```

Register.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import bgImg from "../../assets/r1.png";
import "./Register.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { useNavigate  } from 'react-router-dom';
import { db } from '../../firebase';
import { doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const Register = () => {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
 
  const auth = getAuth();
  const navigateTo  = useNavigate();

  function generateRandomCode(length) {
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let code = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
      code += characters.charAt(randomIndex);
    }
    return code;
  }

  const handleSignup = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError('');

    try {
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      const user = userCredential.user;

      // Generate and store unique approval code in Firestore
      const approvalCode = generateRandomCode(6); 
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), {
        approvalCode,
        approvalStatus: 'pending',
        email,
        password,
      });
      navigateTo("/pending-approval");
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.error('Signup Error:', error);
      setError('An error occurred during signup.');
    }
  };
  


  return (
    <div className="signup">
      <section className="signup-body">
        <div className="register">
          <div className="col-1">
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
            <span>Register and enjoy the service</span>

            <form id="form" className="flex flex-col" onSubmit={handleSignup}>
              <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Enter your password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <button type="submit" className="btn">Sign Up</button>
              <span>Already have an Account? </span>
              <Link className="signinBtn" to="/signin">
                Sign In
              </Link>
            </form>
            {error && <p>{error}</p>}
          </div>
          <div className="col-2">
            <img src={bgImg} alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

SignIn.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import bgImg from "../../assets/r1.png";
import "./SignIn.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { db } from '../../firebase';
import { useNavigate  } from 'react-router-dom';

const SignIn = () => {
  
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [approvalCode, setApprovalCode] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const auth = getAuth();
  
  const navigateTo = useNavigate();

  const handleSignIn = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

      // Retrieve the user's approval code from Firestore
      const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(userCredential.user.uid);
      const userDoc = await userRef.get();

      if (userDoc.exists) {
        const storedApprovalCode = userDoc.data().approvalCode;

        if (approvalCode === storedApprovalCode) {
          // User signed in successfully
          navigateTo('in');
          console.log('User signed in successfully');
        } else {
          setError('Approval code does not match.');
        }
      } else {
        setError('User document not found.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setError('Invalid email or password.');
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="signup">
      <section className="signup-body">
        <div className="register">
          <div className="col-1">
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
            {/* <span>register and enjoy the service</span> */}

            <form id="form" className="flex flex-col" onSubmit={handleSignIn}>
              <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Enter your password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your Code"
                value={approvalCode}
                onChange={(e) => setApprovalCode(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <button type="submit" className="btn">Sign In</button>
              <span>Don't have an Account? </span>
              
                <Link className="signinBtn" to="/register">
                  Sign Up
                </Link>
              
            </form>
            {error && <p>{error}</p>}
          </div>
          <div className="col-2">
            <img src={bgImg} alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

I have tried with the mentioned code. Please help me with this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing the newer modular syntax, where (`getFirestore` and `collection` are top-level functions) with the classic namespaced syntax (where `collection` is a method on the database object). That isn't possible, and you'll have to pick one or the other.

Your namespaced code:

```
const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(userCredential.user.uid);
```

Would look like this in the modular API:

```
const userRef = doc(db, 'users', userCredential.user.uid);
```

Also see:

- [Upgrade from the namespaced API to the modular API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)
- [Firebase Firestore db.collection is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69313691/firebase-firestore-db-collection-is-not-a-function)
- [firestore.collection is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70622848/firestore-collection-is-not-a-function)